# iPhone Debugging: Get a black screen when debugging a universal app

Tags: iphone, debugging, ipod-touch

I am working on my universal app (4.0.1 sdk) and I am unable to get it to run on an iPod touch. It works on iPad, and on both the iPad Simulator and the iPod simulator When I try to launch the app on the touch, my main gets called and I can stop at a break point (I assume this means the provisioning and certs are right) but nothing after that. There isn't anything in the GDB log. I can debug a simple "Hello world" type app on the touch. Anyone have any suggestions of what else to try?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are not using .nib files you might want to make sure the code which creates your window gets executed: `window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];`
2. If you are using .nib (.xib) files make sure you have the window appropriately delegated to the app delegate in interface builder.

In my case I was subclassing an app delegate and I accidently removed the line calling `[super didFinishLaunchingWithOptions...]` where my window was being created.

I hope this helps someone.

Cheers